# Opening combos after getting focus

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

I need  a combo's menu to be open after getting focus automatically. Changing `minchar` config  was not effective. Is there any other config for this purpose?

Update:

```
Ext.define("My.form.combo.Local", {
    extend: "Ext.form.ComboBox",
    xtype: 'local-combo',
    queryMode: 'local',
    minChars: 0,
    selectOnFocus: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent();
        this.on('focus', function () {
            console.log('f');
            this.expand();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snipped worked in ExtJS 4.2.3

You can control the picker with [expand](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-expand) and [collapse](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-collapse)

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
var c =Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

c.on('focus',function(c){c.expand()})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add your suggestion to my base class as added to question. But it does not work. What's wrong with it? Should I use `listeners` instead of `on`?

Comment: @PHPst what dies not work? Dies the listener get called? You should use the First argument of The callback instead of The this keyword

Comment: @sra what about when you click on the combo arrow. Sometimes it closes the combo immediately. Another event gets triggered. How to keep the default mechanism for opening and use this `onfocus` mechanism?

Answer (score -1):

I made a fiddle for you: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fj5

It works like a charm. Maybe you have some other problems in your code.

Comment: Congratulation for copying my answer to a fiddle and posting it as new answer -1

Comment: Thanks a lot. There was another issue in my code. ◕‿◕

Comment: Please consider converting the answer to a comment.

Comment: @ sra: he posted, that your solution doesn't work. So don't be a petty about a clear answer that works. Thanks.